# Having a bit of confusion as to how to write this logic

Tags: javascript

I have a object with two values:

```
fruit.apple and fruit.pear
```

Here are the cases: If my bag has an apple but not a pear, then its true.
If my bag has an apple and a pear then its true. Else then its false. I would like to know if an OR would be the best use case here.

I have:

```
    if (fruit.apple || fruit.pear) {
       return true;
} else {
       return false;             
}
```

Comment: no, because if your bag has only a pear then would return true. Just check `if (fruit.apple) {` or just `return fruit.apple`

Comment: From your description, all you need is `if (fruit.apple)`, since having an apple is apparently the only requirement for the case to be `true`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a pear doesn't make sense. Just do

```
return !!fruit.apple
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of the double negation here?

Comment: To return boolean value. We don't know what type is it.

Answer (score 1):

```
return fruit.apple ? true : false
```